# Crystal report working on development system but not on production system

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm facing a problem with Crystal Reports and VB.NET

The problem is that my code works locally on my machine but when I deploy it, it seems to be having some authentication issues.

After I deployed my project and a client tries to access it, Crystal Reports are now prompting for username and password of my local development SQL Server instance.

http://s8.postimage.org/65syeiblx/untitledfds.png

Any suggestions on what could be causing this problem, and how to correct it?

Comment: Are you missing any keys on your keyboard?

Comment: You are going to need to provide more than a screenshot of the user experience, code is needed here, also relevant details about where and how you deployed your solution.

Comment: @kd7 actually i hav done my report with crystal report wizard....i didnt done ne type of codiing to genrate this report..need more.??
as u may say m beginner in this field i much se this wizard type of features of .net frmwrk..hnce help me to get out of this...thanx in adv

Answer (score 0):

I had faced exactly same problem with my project. All you need to do is use data tables. Fetch data into these data tables using queries. Don't establish connection directly to the database

Comment: bt there should be some way to get out of this na..??

Comment: every time v cnt do such things to get data in datatable n thn use this to generate reports..

Comment: there may be other way but i found this one when it was a crucial stage. Worked out well.